# How to check if given date is within 365 days from now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails newbie question:

Given a datetime from the db in the format `2012-02-12 23:59:30`, how can I check if it's within 365 days from now?

I've tried the following but didn't work: `<%= expedite - Date.today %>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a number of days to `Date.today` and see if the date is on or before that:

```
if expedite <= (Date.today + 365.days)
  # it's within 365 days
end
```

You could also do `Date.today + 1.year` instead, but that will technically add 365.25 days, not 365.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "1 year from now" by 365 days, since checking for 365 days doesn't account for leap years:

```
if expedite <= 1.year.from_now
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution accounts for dates more than a year ago.

```
if (Date.today-365..Date.today+365).include? expedite
  # it's really within 365 days
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding 365 or 365,25 days to a date might not be what you want.
In leap years:

```
require 'date'
start = Date.new(2012,2,1)
puts start + 365 #=> 2013-01-31

# Human "one year from now":
puts start >> 12  #=> 2013-02-01
```